# WebView does not load LimeJS resources

Tags: android, webview, limejs

I made a game with LimeJS and I want to make an Android application for this game. I tested the game with the Android Browser and it worked fine, but when i use the game inside my app in a WebView it didn't work. The web view looks like works well with pages without lime

Here is the code for the WebView:

```
//WebView
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);

//Settings to configure the webViewBrowser to show Flash and respond to links
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

//I changed the url to a LimeJS example
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.limejs.com/static/roundball/index.html");
```

After testing a while I used an Sniffer and I realize that my Android application is not asking for the resources to the server, but the Android Browser makes the calls.

Someone knows how to configure the WebView to make it Works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved using Local Storage.
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

I found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html#WebView) on the android documentation that is useful for debuging a WebApp